# Jest configuration in package.json fails

Tags: reactjs, configuration, package, jestjs, enzyme

[image]

Hello this is the first time I am using Jest. I am trying to configure it work with Enzyme and webpack. I added this to my package.json file for testing:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
  }
```

And the jest configuration:

```
"jest": {
    "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>_tests_/setup/setupEnzyme.js",
    "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/_tests_/setup/"
    ],
    "verbose": true
  }
```

This is my setupEnzyme file:

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

But I get error `Module <rootDir>_tests_/setup/setupEnzyme.js in the setupTestFrameworkScriptFile option was not found.`

Comment: Shouldn't it be `<rootDir>/_tests/...` with slash after rootDir?

Comment: Hey I am not sure but I changed it and there was no difference

Comment: Try it without `<rootDir>`, providing full path to enzymeSetup and check if that would work. And also try to remove `testPathIgnorePatterns`

Comment: where is your setupEnzyme located ?

Comment: Unfortunately still the same error...

Comment: I added a picture _tests_ folder is under src folder

Comment: Maybe the `src` is not a rootDir, i think the problem is definitely about paths resolving/file locations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a `package.json` of my project that uses jest. I have a `src` and `test` folder on the same level.  Unlike you, I am using `setupFiles` array in `jest` object of `package.json`.

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "App",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --colors --mode=development",
    "build": "webpack --mode=production",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:coverage": "jest --coverage"
  },
  "jest": {
    "setupFiles": [
      "./test/jestsetup.js"
    ],
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    }
  },
  "keywords": [
    "react"
  ],
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "^23.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-2": "^6.24.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
    "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^23.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.4.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.21.0",
    "webpack": "^4.6.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.15",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2"
  }
}
```

Here is the `jestsetup.js`

```
import Enzyme, { shallow, render, mount } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
// React 16 Enzyme adapter
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

Answer (score 2):

[image: This is my project folder structure]

**Like this, I mentioned in my package.json**

```
           "jest": {
                 "snapshotSerializers": ["enzyme-to-json/serializer"],
                  "moduleFileExtensions": ["js","jsx" ],
                  "setupTestFrameworkScriptFile": "<rootDir>src/setupTests.js",
                  "moduleNameMapper": {"^.+\\.(css|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
                  },
                  "verbose": true,
                  "transform": {"^.+\\.(js|jsx)$": "babel-jest",
                               "^.+\\.css$": "jest-css",
                               "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|css|json)$)": "jest-file"
                               },
                   "testURL": "http://localhost"
                   },
```